# How to backup the Mongo Atlas M0 Cluster with MongoDump uri using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

how to backup mongoAtlas M0 cluster using mongodump URI. This URI works perfectly in terminal and i got the gzip file. Using spawn I'm calling this URI it is returning error code. Is there any way to backup the M0 Cluster periodically using node-cron.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
 var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
backupMongoDbData();
});

async function backupMongoDbData{

  const child = await spawn('mongodump', [
    "--uri mongodb+srv://DBusername:DBpassword@DBcluster/databaseName",//this is CommandLine tool for Mongodump
    `--archive=./BackupData`,
    '--gzip',
  ]);


  child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout:\n', data);
  });
  child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stderr:\n', Buffer.from(data).toString());
  });
  child.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error:\n', error);
  });
  child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    if (code) console.log('Process exit with code:', code);
    else if (signal) console.log('Process killed with signal:', signal);
    else console.log('Backup is successfull ');
  });
}
```

Comment: Have u solved the problem? I am stuck  to restore my cluster

Answer (score 1):

Try adding '=' after the '--uri'.
Like this:

```
function backupMongoDbData(){
```

const child = spawn('mongodump', [
"--uri=" + uri,//this is CommandLine tool for Mongodump
`--archive=./BackupData`,
'--gzip',
]);